# merging 2D slices into 3D volume in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Seems to be a rather simple question but actually not that easy with no experience in image handling/processing.

I do not just want to stack 2D-arrays on top of each other but create a 3D volume by merging multiple binary 2D slices which are separated by empty space.

Example:
Define a 3D-matrix with zeros:

```
A = np.zeros((100,100,100))
```

Put a rectangular area with ones in the first slice of `A`:

```
A[0,25:75,25:75] = 1
```

Set the value in the middle of the last slice of `A` to one:

```
A[99,50,50] = 1
```

How can I now merge these two slices linearly, so that the result would be a 'pyramid' of ones inside the 3D-volume.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:** The purpose is to be able to select different volumes of interest by defining several 2D regions of interest in several slices. Imagine also for example defining a big circle in slice 0, a small circle in slice 50 and again a bigger circle in slice 100. Resulting volume of interest should be an "hourglass-structure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate distance and angle between every dot at first slice and every dot at the last, when for every step you should linear decrease distance with constant angle.

```
A = np.zeros((100,100,100))
A[0,25:75,25:75] = 1
A[99,50,50] = 1

from math import sin, cos, atan2
dim = 100
for i99,j99 in np.swapaxes(np.where(A[dim-1]==1),0,1):
    for i0,j0 in np.swapaxes(np.where(A[0]==1),0,1):
        di = (i0-i99)
        dj = (j0-j99)
        dist = (di**2 + dj**2)**0.5
        ang = atan2(dj,di)
        for t in range(1,dim-1):
            ndist = dist * (1 - t/dim)
            pi = round(sin(ang)*ndist) + i99
            pj = round(cos(ang)*ndist) + j99
            A[t][pi][pj] = 1
```

Now we should check our code

In [2]:

```
A[96][48:53,48:53]
```

Out[2]:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thank's for the idea! I see one problem. Since in this example we have only one point on the top, this works relatively fast. But if you try this with two rectangulars (pyramid trunk) or bigger data sets (1000x1000x1000 matrices), it would take too long to connect all points with each other. Nevertheless I think I will try to stick with your idea and try some modifications...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are 'merging' things, just setting successive layers of `A` to different values.  Let's simplify the problem by working with a small 2d array.  We can fill it with an 'hour glass' with these simple statements:

```
A=np.zeros((10,11),int)    
for i in range(0,5):
    j=i+1
    A[i, j:-j] = i
for i in range(5,10):
    j=10-i
    A[i, j:-j]=i
```

producing:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0]])
```

Generalizing this to 3d, and to other methods of selecting the slices should be straight forward.

```
A=np.zeros((10,11,11),int)
for i in range(0,5):
    j=i+1
    A[i, j:-j, j:-j] = i
```

setting a circle instead of a square will require more code, but that's another question, isn't it?

Comment: It's not actually 'merging' but I think the word describes the goal here. Of course one could find ways to build structures like an 'hour glass' or 'pyramids' in 2D as well as in 3D just like you showed above. Maybe the example was just too trivial... But imagine you have some 3D MRI data set and want to extract a 3D volume of interest without some fancy image processing software. Selecting a 2D region of interest is relatively easy, so the idea is to do so for e.g. every 50th slice in the 3D data and then 'connect' or 'merge' all of them linearly in order to get an (approximated) 3D volume.